# How to detect device is moving or not using sensor android

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I am using below code to identify the movement of the device, means I would like to know that device is moving or not. I also use Google Activity APIs which provides different activity modes like WALKING, ON_FOOT, STILL, etc without using GPS. I would like to achieve the same with Sensors but I am not able to get it accurately.

The issue with the following code is that as soon as I move the device quickly like take it from the table then I am getting the result as moving whereas it's not actually moving.

```
// calling method from onSensorChanged method and using TYPE_ACCELEROMETER sensor.
double speed = getAccelerometer(event.values);

// then checking the speed.
if(speed > 0.9 && speed < 1.1) {
   // device is not moving
} else {
   // device is moving.
}

/**
     * @return
     */
    private double getAccelerometer(float[] values) {
        // Movement
        float x = values[0];
        float y = values[1];
        float z = values[2];

        float accelerationSquareRoot =
                (float) ((x * x + y * y + z * z) / (9.80665 * 9.80665));

        return Math.sqrt(accelerationSquareRoot);
    }
```

Can anyone guide me how to make this logic accurate so that I can identify the device is moving or not?

Answer (score 0):

The accelerometer is made to return acceleration data and according to Netwon's 2nd law if the acceleration is constant then the body is not moving or moving with constant speed(this is quite impossibile in your case).
Therefore if you keep reading the same data on all three axis(or better in a quite strict range) from accelerometer over time it means the phone is not moving otherwise it is.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose, you need to use Activity Recognition API which will provide you some events like moving, stop, driving, e.t.c, And activity recognize use some sensor data and also help of location service when is running. For the more how we can use and what actually it. You can read from below link

https://developers.google.com/location-context/activity-recognition/

Comment: it's really bad, has big delays, we need it in real-time

Comment: The Activity Recognition API is HORRIBLE. Rarely works reliably with large delays.